# How to set schedule for workers to do same task but in different shifts

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have a service block that contains 3 workers (a resource pool). Now (resource pool), 3 workers work on the schedule, which is given below.
[image]

According to the schedule, all three workers are doing two shifts. The first shift is from 4 a.m. to 2 a.m., and the second shift is from 2 p.m. to 11 p.m. I'd like to have two workers do the first shift and one worker do the second shift.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using type on/off for your schedule, but you can also use an integer, which will allow you to define how many resources you get in each shift.

Comment: Thank you very much; it works. Only have one problem with animation. For example, if in shift 1 we have two workers and in shift 2 we have three workers, the animation of the workers does not change from two workers to three workers when the shift changes.